# How does web application communicate with different systems through text file?

Tags: node.js, web-applications, system, communication

I have developed a web application in **node.js** express framework. I have different systems that are used for various purposes.

When I call **REST** endpoints it should communicate with those systems and collect data. I want to know how can make my web application communicate to this system over a text file.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why do you need to use a text file, but if I understand correctly, what you need is basically something like Redis or Kafka. It would allow you to create kind of a "central" process where you can save/read information.

https://redis.io/

https://kafka.apache.org/

There're more options out there, just start with these ones and try to figure out if it's exactly what you need.